# The hidden wx.Frame is shown automatically and can not be hidden after restoring from minimize

Tags: winforms, wxpython, show, hidden

*Python 3.7+wxPython 4.0.6 (same as 4.0.2)+windows 10 (64-bit)*

Because I need a sub frame which can floating on main frame, so use style: wx.FRAME_FLOAT_ON_PARENT.

Operations: First open the sub frame, then minimize the main frame. After restoring from minimize, hide the sub frame (using Hide()). Then minimize->restore again. **The sub frame is shown automatically, and can not be hidden.**
I have tested that at this time, frame.IsShown() returns False.

Sample as follows.

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, id=-1, parent=parent, size=wx.Size(600, 500),
                          title='Test')
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, id=-1, pos=(200, 300))
        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel, id=-1, label='button',
                                 pos=wx.Point(20, 56), size=wx.Size(87, 28))
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton, id=-1)
        self.frame = MyFrame(self)
    def OnButton(self, event):
        self.frame.Show()
        event.Skip()
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        style = wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX | \
                wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR | wx.FRAME_FLOAT_ON_PARENT
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, id=-1, parent=parent, size=wx.Size(300, 200),
                          title='Sub', style=style)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
    def OnClose(self, evt):
        self.Hide()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I do not need to close the sub frame. I need to hide it.

The detail operations are:

1. Click the button to open the sub frame.
2. Click the minimize button of the main frame. (-> All the frames are minimized.)
3. Click the icon in taskbar to restore the main frame.
4. Click the "×" button of the sub frame.
5. Click the minimize button of the main frame again.
6. Click the icon in taskbar to restore the main frame.

-> Problem: the sub frame is shown. And can not use "×" button to hide it.

I need the sub frame shown on main frame when it loses focus, so I used wx.FRAME_FLOAT_ON_PARENT.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe using wxPython 4.0.4, python 3.7 and macOS. But anyway, I do not think that you will be able to close `MyFrame` using the GUI because you are modifying the normal behavior of the `wx.EVT_CLOSE` event and do not include `self.Destroy()` or equivalent in the `MyFrame.OnClose` method. With your code, the only way to close `MyFrame` is to close the `MainFrame` because you make `MyFrame` a child of `MainFrame`.

Nevertheless, with your code, if `MyFrame` is minimized then I cannot see it again by pressing the button. I changed your code a little bit and now I can hide/minimize and then show/restore `MyFrame`. I needed to remove `wx.FRAME_FLOAT_ON_PARENT` for the `Restore()` method to properly work. Hope this helps.

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, id=-1, parent=parent, size=wx.Size(600, 500),
                          title='Test')
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, id=-1, pos=(200, 300))
        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel, id=-1, label='button',
                                 pos=wx.Point(20, 56), size=wx.Size(87, 28))
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton, id=-1)
        self.frame = MyFrame(self)
    def OnButton(self, event):
        if self.frame.IsShown():
            self.frame.Restore()
        else:
            self.frame.Show()


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        style = wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX | \
                wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, id=-1, parent=parent, size=wx.Size(300, 200),
                          title='Sub', style=style)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
    def OnClose(self, evt):
        self.Hide()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```